# Did not get expected result in Go playground

Tags: go, concurrency, parallel-processing, goroutine

I have a very simple go code like this:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Printf("No %d goroutine begin\n", i)
            fmt.Printf("No %d goroutine is done\n", i)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

On my local computer, with 12 core CPU, this code will output randomly like expected.
But when I run the code in the [go playground environment](https://play.golang.org/p/HZvAHrJYKH7), I get an unexpected result. I know the Go playground only uses one core to run the code, so the expected output should be one by one from *No 0 goroutine begin*, but it always starts with the last number *No 9 goroutine begin*. Is that correct or did am I missing something?

Comment: Goroutines are independent concurrent tasks; there isn't any implicit ordering between the operations they run

Comment: You can't expect any particular order without synchronization. There is no incorrect order. That being said, the playground caches output, so nothing is going to change unless you change the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go playground has a modified scheduler and other special features.

[The Go Blog: Inside the Go Playground](https://blog.golang.org/playground)

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/): About